# Determine if Tor works

Tags: proxy, tor, ip

I have installed Tor on my Mint computer, but how do I determine if Tor is working? When I visit http://whatismyip.com, my old IP is shown. Should it not be a different IP when I'm using Tor?

Here is some information when I run netstat -ant | grep 9050

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://check.torproject.org/

Make sure you have setup your browser to use the proxy, you can use something like foxy proxy to be able to switch between TOR and normal browsing quickly.